# Meth dealer reference in Family Guy

Tags: reference, family-guy

In the 'Peter Buys a Farm' episode of Family Guy there is a joke in which Stewie goes to a pharmacy to buy cold medicine and there is a poster on the wall entitled "Known meth dealers" which has pictures of Peter, Lois, Chris and an unidentified girl:

[image]

What is this a reference to?

Comment: She's actually mentioned by name in the episode; 'she' (not actually her voice) show up at Peter's house at the end, begging for drugs, and Peter says her name.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's [Jodie Lee-Ann Sweetin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodie_Sweetin), an actress and recovered drug addict, who wrote a book about it, called *unSweetined*.

She [tweeted](https://twitter.com/jodiesweetin/status/334430044690739200?lang=en) about it in 2013:

> @SethMacFarlane I love Family Guy and was so stoked to have made it the ranks of being made fun of by you. Seriously, honored! Haha!!

Comment: I knew the reference, but thanks for including her tweet. Nice to see she has a sense of humour about it!